SORT formula with empy column in data range and descending order based on another column (not the first column in the data range)



0
A
B
C




1
Project A

500


2
Project B

200


3
Project C

600


4
Project D

300


5
Project E

100


6





7
Project C
600



8
Project A
500



9
Project D
300



10
Project B
200



11
Project E
100





In Range A7:B11 I want to sort the values from Range A1:A5 descending based on the values in Range C1:C5. Therefore, I tried to go with this formula:
=SORT(A1:C5;;-1)

However, when I do this the result looks like this:

How do I need to modify the SORT formula to 

get the list in the correct descending order based on the values in Range C1:C5? 
ignore the empty Column B within the Range A1:C5 and not displaying 0 values for it?


HSTACK(A1:A5,C1:C5) before sorting:
=SORT(HSTACK(A1:A5,C1:C5),2,-1)


Or use CHOOSECOLS:
=SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A1:C5,1,3),2,-1)



Thanks for the answer. I prefer the solution with HSTACK because it works independently from how many columns are between the ranges.

You just need to specify column number to sort base on that column. Try-
=SORT(A1:C5,3,-1)

Another way is to use SORTBY().
=SORTBY(A1:C5,C1:C5,-1)



Comma (,) and semicolon (;) depends on regional settings.

Thanks for the answer. And how can I get rid of the 0 and put the numbers in the results in Range B8:B12 and not in C8:C12?

@Michi I'd recommend =CHOOSECOLS(A1:C5;1;3), which would give you =SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A1:C5;1;3);2;-1) (if I'm not mistaken)

@Excellor Yes, if OP wants to skip column 2 then choose column would be good choice. Hstack is another alternative.

=LET(x,SORT(A1:C5,3,-1),IF(x="","",x))
